# Error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am getting an error `error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`

in line

```
BookingAdapter expListAdapter = new BookingAdapter (this, listDataHeader,  listDataChild);
try{
explistView.SetAdapter (expListAdapter);
explistView.SetGroupIndicator (null);
}
catch(Exception e) {
Toast.MakeText (this,e+"",ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

and here is my piece of code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using SalonServices;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace PariSalon
{
[Activity (Label = "BookingRequest")]           
public class BookingRequest : Activity
{
    public List<GetServices> listDataHeader;
    public List<GetServices> services;
    Dictionary<GetServices, List<String>> listDataChild;
    ExpandableListView explistView;
    public static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://xxx.xxx.Xx.xx/SalonService/SalonServices.svc");
    //public static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://xxxx");
    private SalonServicesClient serviceClient;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Booking_request);
        InitializeSalonServiceClient();
        Button submit = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button2);


        //string userid = "1";
        //serviceClient.GetServicesForUserAsync (userid);
        string userid = "1";
        serviceClient.GetServicesForUserAsync (userid);
        //serviceClient.GetServicesForUserAsync (userid);

        submit.Click += delegate {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Booking_Request_sent));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };


        // Create your application here
        /*          

        explistView.SetOnGroupClickListener( new OnGroupClickListener());

//Catch click event attempt 2
        explistView.GroupClick += (object pobjSender,   ExpandableListView.GroupClickEventArgs pArgs) =>
        {
            int len = expListAdapter.GroupCount;
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {

                if(i!=groupPosition)
                {
                    explistView.CollapseGroup(i);
                }
                if(i==groupPosition){
                    if(explistView.IsGroupExpanded(groupPosition)){
                        explistView.CollapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    }
                    else {
                        explistView.ExpandGroup(groupPosition);
                    }


                }
            }
        };*/
    }
    private void InitializeSalonServiceClient()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();
        serviceClient = new SalonServicesClient(binding, EndPoint);
        //serviceClient.GetServicesForUserCompleted += GetServicesForUserCompleted;
        //serviceClient.GetProductDetailsCompleted += GetProductDetailsCompleted;
        serviceClient.GetServicesForUserCompleted += GetServicesForUserCompleted;

    }


    private void GetServicesForUserCompleted(object sender, GetServicesForUserCompletedEventArgs getServiceDataCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        string msg = null;

        if (getServiceDataCompletedEventArgs.Error != null)
        {
            msg = getServiceDataCompletedEventArgs.Error.Message;
        }
        else if (getServiceDataCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled)
        {
            msg = "Request was cancelled.";
        }
        else
        {
            services = new List<GetServices>(getServiceDataCompletedEventArgs.Result);
            prepareListData ();
            explistView = FindViewById<ExpandableListView> (Resource.Id.expandableselectservicetype);
            BookingAdapter expListAdapter = new BookingAdapter (this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
            try{
                explistView.SetAdapter (expListAdapter);
                explistView.SetGroupIndicator (null);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.MakeText (this,e+"",ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }


        }

    }

    private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            Name = "basicHttpBinding",
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
        };
        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 50);
        binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        return binding;
    }


    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new List<GetServices>();
        listDataChild = new Dictionary<GetServices, List<String>>();
        listDataHeader.Clear ();
        if (services != null) {
            foreach (GetServices pd in services) {
                listDataHeader.Add (pd);
            }
            // Adding child data
            //listDataHeader.Add("Top 250/n");
            //listDataHeader.Add("Now Showing");
            //listDataHeader.Add("Coming Soon..");      

            List<String> childLabel = new List<String> ();
            childLabel.Add ("Date :");
            childLabel.Add ("Time :");
            childLabel.Add ("User :");
            childLabel.Add ("Second User:");
            childLabel.Add ("Status :");
            childLabel.Add ("Cancel ");

            listDataChild.Add (listDataHeader.ElementAt (0), childLabel); // Header, Child data
            listDataChild.Add (listDataHeader.ElementAt (1), childLabel);
            listDataChild.Add (listDataHeader.ElementAt (2), childLabel);
        }
    }


}
}
```

I have another adapter class but I think the error is only in this class. How can I solve this problem. Can any one please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `GetServicesForUserCompleted` method from `SalonServicesClient` on worker thread. Invoke it on the [UI thread](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/) instead.

Comment: yes I got the answer thank you for your support. +1 for your ans

Comment: The link provided is for iOS only. It doesn't have any direct relevance to Android implementation which is what the question relates to.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a cross platform solution in xamarin for this issue;

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
 {
   //Your code here
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

The linked article in the accepted answer talks about `InvokeOnMainThread` which is an IOS thing. No idea why it was accepted as an answer for Android as the question is tagged.

For Android you use `Activity.RunOnUiThread`. Relevant documentation is here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/writing_responsive_applications/

Because you are rigging this up from somewhere that inherits from `Activity` you can just wrap the relevant code so this:

```
BookingAdapter expListAdapter = new BookingAdapter (this, listDataHeader,  listDataChild);
try{
    explistView.SetAdapter (expListAdapter);
    explistView.SetGroupIndicator (null);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.MakeText (this,e+"",ToastLength.Long).Show();   
}
```

becomes:

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    BookingAdapter expListAdapter = new BookingAdapter (this, listDataHeader,  listDataChild);
    try{
        explistView.SetAdapter (expListAdapter);
        explistView.SetGroupIndicator (null);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.MakeText (this,e+"",ToastLength.Long).Show();   
    }
});
```

That's really all there is to it.