# Update view - Reactive Extensions

Tags: android, xamarin, rx.net

I've got following code:

> Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500)).SubscribeOn(XXX).ObserveOn(YYY).Subscribe(
>               t => SendCounter(t),
>               e => HandleException(e));

Where XXX, YYY are `Schedulers`.

Inside SendCounter(t) I set a text with t value.

The problem is that when I run the code I got this error:

```
'only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views'
```

I'm using this component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/rxforxamarin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views in xamarin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162096/error-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-view)

Comment: not too sure how to Use ObserveOn() and SubcribeOn() myself in xamarin. tried Scheduler.NewThread but thats deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var uiThread = SynchronizationContext.Current;

Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500))
    .SubscribeOn(XXX)
    .ObserveOn(uiThread)
    .Subscribe( t => SendCounter(t), e => HandleException(e));
```

Comment: This is what i needed!

Comment: what do I subscribe on? how do i use this scheduler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579237/whats-the-difference-between-subscribeon-and-observeon

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you Observe on the main thread so that you can affect the view directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ReactiveUI use your code like this for e.g:

```
searchButton
.SelectMany(async x => await executeSearch(x))
.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
.ToProperty(this, x => x.SearchResults, out searchResults);
```

[ReactiveUI handbook](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/asynchronous-operations)