# Xamarin Forms PCL with Caliburn, only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

In my Xamarin Forms PCL, I'm using Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms to implement the MVVM data binding. The structure of the project has a viewModel and a view and the data binding is done like this:
In the viewModel

```
private BindableCollection<TempListItem> _temperatures;
        public BindableCollection<TempListItem> Temperatures
        {
            get { return _temperatures; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _temperatures)
                {
                    _temperatures = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Temperatures);
                }
            }
        }
```

In the view

```
var t2Name = new Label
            {
                FontSize = 17,
                TextColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["ForegroundColor"]
            };
            t2Name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Temperatures[1].Name"));
```

I have this problem `only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` that arise when I navigate to another page and I suppose is related to the data bindings.

```
_navigationService.For<MainViewModel>().Navigate();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views in xamarin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162096/error-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-view)

Comment: Can you provide more information about where this line of code is being called? `_navigationService.For<MainViewModel>().Navigate();`

Comment: `public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
public async void Login()
{
_navigationService.For<MainViewModel>().Navigate();
}
}`
In LoginView.xaml

`<Button Grid.Row="5"  Margin="8, 2, 8, 2" Text="LOGIN"  cm:Message.Attach="[Event Clicked]=[Action Login]" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  BorderWidth="0" BackgroundColor="#2FD1FF" TextColor="White" />`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue by calling the invocation in the main thread that "drawed" the UI.
For example, in the click button event handler:

```
    private void btnSarasa_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
            () => { lblStatus.Text = "Sarasa"; }
        );
    }
```

Or in another event handler:

```
    private void Ws_OnOpened()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
            () =>
            {
                ws.Send(@"{""protocol"":""json"",""version"":1}" + recordSeparator);
                lblStatus.Text = "WS abierto";
                ws.Send("{\"arguments\":[\"" + "444" + "-1\"],\"invocationId\":\"" + "0" + "\",\"target\":\"JoinGroup\",\"type\":1}" + recordSeparator);
            }
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible solution for your issue.
You could call the Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync in case you need the refresh to be that way, I mean, Async.
It also admits "typing" the task results.
In that case, use this:

```
Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync<string>
```